# very detailed inventory selection with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am designing a new ansible implement on an existing system.  The existing system is a large hardware test platform.  I need to be able to do things like:

`run task xyz on all version 3 hosts that are using a Broadcom BCM57412 network controller.`

or

`run task xyz on all hosts in group QA2 that have firmware version 3 and HGST hard drives`

I have been reading the inventory capabilities with Ansible, and since it doesn't appear to have conditional inventory selects, I'm assuming that im going to need to use an external inventory database.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, tasks should do at least part of their own selection based on what system facts apply.

For instance, you may write a task which applies to a specific model of hard drive:

```
name: Upgrade firmware on HGST HUH728080AL5200 drive
command: /usr/bin/whatever arguments ...
when: ansible_devices['sda']['model'] == 'HGST HUH728080AL5200'
```

This doesn't necessarily need inventory selection, as it will only run on hosts which have the named model drive (as sda; looping through installed drives is left as an exercise to the reader).

Answer (score 2):

Ansible can collect facts about your systems. Using the 'setup' module.  Run either directly as a task, or via the 'gather_facts: yes' play keyword.

If you configure your fact caching and set gathering to be explicit, then create facts that cover all the variations of information you would want to query on, then you should be able to run plays based on cached facts, by constructing a dynamic group.

ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = data/fact_cache
fact_caching_timeout = 86400
gathering = explicit
```

We could run a play like this

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  # simple example, you could use any facts you have
  # make your filter as complex as you want.
  - name: construct a group of systems based on facts
    group_by:
      key: filtered_systems
    when: ansible_distribution is defined and ansible_distribution == 'Debian' and
          ansible_architecture is defined and ansible_architecture == 'x86_64'

  - name: report the systems
    debug:
      var: groups['filtered_systems']
      verbosity: 1
    run_once: true

- hosts: filtered_systems
  tasks:
  - name: simple ping of the systems
    ping:
```